# Clear command with contents of messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to log in console messages contents that depend on the amount value.
PS: I'm working with discord.js v12

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
const amount = args[1]

const maxamount = 99;
const minamount = 2;

if(amount) {
    const mesCont = 
    message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then(messages => {
        console.log(messages.content)
    }) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then(messages => messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.content)))
```

This will log the message content for the amount of messages you provided.